# Get Magento menu from anywhere in html?

Tags: template, category-products

Is it possible to have the magento category menu available from anywhere in the phtml templates? I have searched for about an hour with no results.

There must be some global function to get the product category menu from anywhere in a html? Who can point me in right direction thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the block `catalog/navigation`

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such function. You can get the layout object and then try to find the reference to the topMenu block, but why would you? Manipulating that will have mixed results at best.

What are you trying to accomplish that you want access to that block anywhere, anytime?

You can assign the block as a child of the block you want it in though.